# how to manipulate graphics created with Adobe Animate CC?

Tags: adobe-animate

So I have created some fancy graphics with Adobe Animate (HTML CANVAS)and added some animation as well. Is there a way to manipulate (or simply get) the Javascript code that generated these graphics? Say I want to use these same graphics in another project. How to extract that code? The generated code is not just simple CreateJS code. It is very tight to the Animate framework.

Answer (score 0):

The code is in fact just plain CreateJS (EaselJS) code. In your generated lib file, you can see all the Graphic instructions for each Shape. For Animate, it uses a "compressed" format by default (which you can actually [see in the docs](https://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_decodePath)). Since 95% of developers don't care what the exported graphics look like, so it uses a custom compression format to reduce the amount of code that is generated, which results in a much smaller filesize.

You can easily pop into the publish settings, and under "Advanced" turn off the "Compact Shapes" option, which will give you typical `lineTo().moveTo().drawRect()` commands again.

[image: Screenshot of Settings]

Hope that helps!